# How to display BBpress statistics?

Tags: bbpress, statistics

This seems like a fairly simple question, and I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but how does one display forum statistics (registered users, posts, etc.)? I see there is a template in the theme compatibility folder called `page-forum-statistics.php` which seems to display some of this info but I'd like it to display in the footer on the homepage.

Is there something I'm missing? Or do they have to be called manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems BBPress got a function called [`bbp_get_statistics()` <sup>read source</sup>](http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.0/bbp-includes/bbp-common-functions.php#L400). You can throw an array of `$args = array();` in it.

You also have a filter to modify the output:

```
apply_filters( 'bbp_get_statistics', $statistics, $args );
```

*Disclaimer: I'm no BBPress expert - I haven't even installed it somewhere, just found this via google.*